# Not a single method can be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse

I couldn't find a propper title for my problem, so I'm going to explain this the best I can so you can understand it and help with my problems.

I've got 3 classes, 1 of them is the main one(sudoku), one class board(Tablero), and one class box(casilla) (the board is made of boxes).
The problem comes when I want to create a new Tablero in the main class, the Tablero has 2 int in the constructor.

If I put both ints when creating it Tablero t(int, int); , in Casilla.h, Casilla.cpp, Tablero.cpp , an error shows saying in the Casilla ones : "undefined reference to 'vtable for Casilla'" and in the Tablero shows : "undefined reference to 'vtable for Tablero'", and in the main one all the methods using Tablero: Multiple markers at this line
    - undefined reference to 'Casilla::~Casilla()' (when the method uses Casilla too)
    - undefined reference to 'Tablero::getCasillac(int, 
     int)'
    - Line breakpoint: Sudoku.cpp [line: /the line]

Also, when I initialitze Tablero t(); , all those others problems don't show, but I can't use any method on the main class. I tried to initialitze it like this and then give Tablero the  parameters with getters and setters, but didn't work. I'll post the important part of the code needed to understand the problem (Tablero and Casilla constructors and part of the main where the problem remains).

Casilla.h:

```
#ifndef CASILLA_H_
#define CASILLA_H_


using namespace std;

class Casilla {
public:
int fila;
int columna;
int numero;
Casilla();

void SetCasillaFull (int _fila, int _columna, int _numero);
void SetNumeroCasilla (int _numero);
int GetNumero();
void SetCasillaPosition (int _fila, int _columna);
};

 /* namespace std */

#endif /* CASILLA_H_ */
```

Casilla.cpp constructor:

```
 // default constructor
 Casilla::Casilla()
 : fila(-1)
 , columna(-1)
 , numero(0)
 { }
```

Tablero.h:

```
#ifndef TABLERO_H_
#define TABLERO_H_
#include "Casilla.h"
#include <vector>
 using namespace std;

class Tablero {
public:
 int filas_;
 int columnas_;

Tablero(int filas,int columnas);

void setcol(int n);
void setfilas(int n);
vector<vector<Casilla> > getCasilla();

void setCasillac(int n ,int t, Casilla c);
Casilla getCasillac(int n ,int t);
};

 /* namespace std */

#endif /* TABLERO_H_ */
```

Tablero.cpp constructor:

```
 Tablero::Tablero(int filas,int columnas)
   // The above is an initialization list
  // We initialize casilla_ as a vector of filas vectors of columnas     Casillas

  {filas_=filas;
   columnas_=columnas;}
 Casilla getCasillac(int n ,int t){
 return casilla_[n][t];

  }
 void setCasillac(int n ,int t,Casilla c){
  casilla_[n][t] = c;

  }
```

Sudoku (main class) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "entorno.h"
#include "Tablero.h"
#include "Casilla.h"
using namespace std;
Tablero t(); //I create it here so I can use it in all the class, also, if I create in a method, the same error shows up.

 void runDemo() {
 t.getCasillac(i,j).SetNumeroCasilla(//int something//);
 t.setCasillac(int,int, casilla);
 }

  int main() {

  runDemo();

  return 0;
   }
  }
```

If you need any more code just say it. I'm an experienced java programmer that never has going out programming in Java in Netbeans, and I'm trying to make a sudoku, although I know the basics about the object oriented programming, I'm finding hard all those .cpp and .h of c++ and it's way to create objects.

Thanks to anyone who explains me where the problem is, because I really wish to learn from my errors, not only to repair them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't define the `Casilla` destructor anywhere, but you don't really need one either.  Remove the line `virtual ~Casilla()` from the class definition.  If you don't want to do this then you need to define the destructor in Casilla.cpp:

```
Casilla::~Casilla() { }
```

The same goes for your `Tablero` class -- you declare an unnecessary destructor but don't define it.

The reason you're getting an error about the vtable is due to how virtual methods are typically implemented.  In order for the vtable to be property built, *every virtual member* must be defined at link time, and you didn't define the virtual destructor anywhere.

In addition, you use the method `Tablero::getCasillac()` but you haven't defined it either.  Provide a definition in Tablero.cpp.

Comment: The vtable errors are not because the linker can't find method definitions. It's because the destructor happens to be the *key function* of the class. The key function is an optimization by compilers they make to avoid creating the vtable in every translation unit the header appears in. They pick one function as the key function, and only emit the vtable when they see the definition of the key function. Since the key function is the destructor here, and the destructor has no definition, the vtable doesn't get emitted either.

Comment: I just erased the virtual things from Tablero and Casilla, and now I can put tablero(int,int); But I get the error - undefined reference to `Tablero::getCasillac(int, int)' , same for setCasillaC although it's defined in Tablero.h. I changed the code in the main post to show how my program looks like, Why do I keep getting this error?

Comment: @SebastianRedl Sure, but if you do omit a virtual method definition even if the key member is defined, you will continue to get undefined reference errors. You still have to define all virtual members if you have any virtual members because they are referenced by the vtable even if they are not actually invoked in any translation unit.

Comment: @flaixman But you didn't define the method `Tablero::setCasillac()`. Instead you defined the free function `setCasillac()`. Change your definition to `void Tablero::setCasillac(int n ,int t,Casilla c)` ...

Comment: Ooooh I see, omg it worked. Really thank you for your patience with me, I'm beggining to hate how hard the logic is c++ compared to java hahahaha.

Upvotes for everyone here, thanks for your help, it's working!